# Clicking one radio button affects another despite separate FormControl instances

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with radio buttons in my Angular application. Despite using separate `FormControl` instances and unique `for` and `id` attributes for each pair of radio buttons, clicking on one radio button also selects the corresponding button in another pair.

Here's the simplified code snippet demonstrating the issue:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <div>
      <input id="foo" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl" [value]="true">
      <label for="foo">foo</label>
      <input id="bar" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl" [value]="false">
      <label for="bar">bar</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input id="foox" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl2" [value]="true">
      <label for="foox">foox</label>
      <input id="barx" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl2" [value]="false">
      <label for="barx">barx</label>
    </div>
    {{formControl.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  formControl = new FormControl();
  formControl2 = new FormControl();
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Could someone please assist in identifying why clicking on one radio button affects another despite having distinct `FormControl` instances and unique identifiers for each radio button pair?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lf3oe7?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: <input type="radio" formControlName="formControl" value="true" />  try attributes without square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, all radio buttons are treated as the same group.

> Radio buttons are normally presented in radio groups (a collection of radio buttons describing a set of related options). Only one radio button in a group can be selected at the same time.

Hence, when you select one of the radio buttons from the row will affect the value (display) selection of the radio button in another row, although when you check the `formControl2.value` it shows `null`.

Thus, you need to provide the `name` attribute to the radio button to represent the radio buttons in different groups.

Reference: [HTML input type="radio"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)

```
<input id="foo" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl" name="group1" [value]="true">
<input id="bar" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl" name="group1" [value]="false">

<input id="foox" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl2" name="group2" [value]="true">
<input id="barx" type="radio" [formControl]="formControl2" name="group2" [value]="false">
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bd8alr?file=src%2Fmain.ts)